# python error in implementing csv file

Tags: python-3.x

i am getting this error when i try to run quora duplicates files on my feature python file,
the part of code i am running is below

```
data = pd.read_csv('train.csv', sep='\t')
data = data.drop(['id', 'qid1', 'qid2'], axis=1)
```

and the output is

```
unfile('/Volumes/Macintosh HD/chrome/is_that_a_duplicate_quora_question-master/feature_engineering.py', wdir='/Volumes/Macintosh HD/chrome/is_that_a_duplicate_quora_question-master')

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-31-e29a1095cc40>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('/Volumes/Macintosh HD/chrome/is_that_a_duplicate_quora_question-master/feature_engineering.py', wdir='/Volumes/Macintosh HD/chrome/is_that_a_duplicate_quora_question-master')

File "/Users/Yash/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "/Users/Yash/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/chrome/is_that_a_duplicate_quora_question-master/feature_engineering.py", line 55, in <module>
data = data.drop(['id','qid1','qid2'], axis=1)

File "/Users/Yash/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2530, in drop
obj = obj._drop_axis(labels, axis, level=level, errors=errors)

File "/Users/Yash/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2562, in _drop_axis
new_axis = axis.drop(labels, errors=errors)

File "/Users/Yash/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3744, in drop
labels[mask])

ValueError: labels ['id' 'qid1' 'qid2'] not contained in axis
```

my csv file is like this

```
"id","qid1","qid2","question1","question2","is_duplicate"
"0","1","2","What is the step by step guide to invest in share market in india?","What is the step by step guide to invest in share market?","0"
"1","3","4","What is the story of Kohinoor (Koh-i-Noor) Diamond?","What would happen if the Indian government stole the Kohinoor (Koh-i-Noor) diamond back?","0"
```

please help me in trying to figure out the problem

Comment: `sep='\t'` means use tab as a separator but looks like your data is comma-separated. `sep=','` might work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to remove the separator argument  `\` because content in csv already has `,` as a separator:

```
# sample.csv file contains following data

"id","qid1","qid2","question1","question2","is_duplicate"
"0","1","2","What is the step by step guide to invest in share market in india?","What is the step by step guide to invest in share ,"0"
"1","3","4","What is the story of Kohinoor (Koh-i-Noor) Diamond?","What would happen if the Indian government stole the Kohinoor(-i-Noor) diamond back?","0"
```

---

```
df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
data = df.drop(['id', 'qid1', 'qid2'], axis=1)
print data
```

---

```
#output will be like this:
"question1","question2","is_duplicate"
"What is the step by step guide to invest in share market in india?","What is the step by step guide to invest in share ,"0"
"What is the story of Kohinoor (Koh-i-Noor) Diamond?","What would happen if the Indian government stole the Kohinoor(-i-Noor) diamond back?","0"
```